# Access database and Java without ODBC

Tags: java, database, ms-access

I want to manipulate a Microsoft Access database (.accdb or .mdb file) from my Java project. I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/healthmarketscience/jackcess/util/ErrorHandler
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:260)
    at Agents.ConnectBDD.main(ConnectBDD.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.util.ErrorHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 3 more
```

How do I solve the error?

Comment: You might consider using [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html). More details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390).

Answer (score 0):

As error stated `com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.util.ErrorHandler.class` does not exist under class. If its a maven project add module containing as dependency under pom or if its java project, compile it and put it under classpath